# How to change Chore properties in cognos-tm1 process?

Tags: cognos-10, cognos-tm1

I need to turn on\off chore or change it's start time during proceess regarding some conditions, how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it's possible by using TI. It might be possible through REST API.
But you may store chore time of execution in the cube. And create a special chore which would check condition (cube cell value = current time) in  every minute/two and run target process.